# Write public key on a file and read with objectInputStream

Tags: java, exception, encryption, objectoutputstream

I need to save a public key in a file and then read.
So, i do this mainly steps:

```
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
```

Then i save with objectOutputStream

Now i creae an objetInputStream with the file that contains that key.
Now im doing:

```
PublicKey pub = (PublicKey)pReader.readObject();
```

And i get the exception:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl cannot be cast to java.security.PublicKey.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you must be saving the private key, not the public key.

Comment: Thanks, yes, i swap the arguments